# Converting RGB pixels to greyscale makes dark pixels appear bluish

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I'm currently experimenting with images in Java and was trying to convert a RGB image to greyscale using the BufferedImage class.

My idea was to get the RGB values of every pixels and set them to (R+G+B)/3:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(file));

int[] pixel;
int r, g, b;

for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) 
    {
        pixel = image.getRaster().getPixel(x, y, new int[3]);

        r = pixel[0];
        g = pixel[1];
        b = pixel[2];
        int gr = (int)((r+g+b)/3);

        String hex = Integer.toHexString(gr)+Integer.toHexString(gr)+Integer.toHexString(gr);
        int i = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);

        image.setRGB(x, y, i);
    }
}

ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("im2.jpg"));
```

The result was this:

[image]

[image]

Regardless of the fact that this is probably the most inefficient way of converting an image to greyscale, I have no idea why this is happening.
What am I missing here?

Comment: It looks cool though :p

Comment: What happens when gr=(r+g+b)/3 is less than 16 (0x10)?  Your string concatenation will be incorrect.  EG  gr=9,  then hex will be "999"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the hex value is not 2-digits. E.G. `Integer.toHexString(10)` returns "a".

So, for example, if `r = 10` and `g = 10` and `b = 10` you will be doing `Integer.toHexString("aaa")` which is quite blue (`aa` = `170`) with a tinge of green (`a` = 10) and no red. This effect will clearly happen more in dark areas of the image and result in mostly blue but some greenish effect.

Here's a blowup of a small section of your image showing the blueing and slight greening.

[image: A sample from your image showing blues and a little green]

To fix it, roll the numbers in properly.

```
image.setRGB(x, y, new Color(gr,gr,gr).getRGB());
```

Answer (score 2):

When your grey value gets lower then 16, it will no longer be an 2 digit hex number. So your hex string will look like "444" instead of "040404". This will result in a blue color.

Why dont you use

```
Color myColor = new Color(gr, gr, gr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

int gr = (int)((r+g+b)/3);

```
    String hex = Integer.toHexString(gr)+Integer.toHexString(gr)+Integer.toHexString(gr);
    int i = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);

    image.setRGB(x, y, i);
```

try this:

Color newColor = new Color(r+g+b,r+g+b,r+g+b);

```
           image.setRGB(j,i,newColor.getRGB());
```